# C# Clear list not working properly

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I´m trying to do a function that go over my entire data structure and save a GameObject x and y position onto two different lists. My main problem is this function is gonna execute everytime so I need to clear the list everytime the code is executed but, I dont know why, the List.Clear() function is not working properly. When I execute this code:

```
public void updateChild()
{
    listaXBaldas.Clear();
    listaYBaldas.Clear();
    hueco1.updateChildAux();
    hueco2.updateChildAux();

}

private void updateChildAux()
{

    if (division == -1) return;
    else
    {
        aux1 = balda.transform.position.y;
        aux2 = balda.transform.position.x;
        listaYBaldas.Add(aux1);
        listaXBaldas.Add(aux2);
        Debug.Log(listaXBaldas.Count);
        hueco1.updateChildAux();
        hueco2.updateChildAux();
    }
}
```

It saves the position as I want, but it doesnt clear the list since the List.Count() is increasing with every execution. I also tried creating a new List instead of clearing it, but I got the same problem.

Comment: Where do you call the function `updateChild` ?

Comment: Is it possible the lists are being accessed from other threads? Because the `Clear` method will actually clear the list.

Comment: Do you have some recursive structure? What are hueco1 and 2?

Comment: It looks like you're calling the clear and the additions on different objects. Or are they static?

Comment: Rule #1:  When there is a bug and you don't know if it's your code or the .NET library (which goes through vast amounts of testing and is being used by millions of people worldwide), it's ALWAYS going to be your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, i set the List as static and it works fine now